# docker container with user created, where on host

Tags: docker, containers

I have a dockerfile with a user created so it is not running as root(best pratice)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime

RUN groupadd -g 1001 appuser && useradd -r -u 1001 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp32.dll"]
```

I build the image and run the container:

```
docker build  -f Dockerfile1 -t myappimage .
docker run -d --name myapp myappimage
```

And then check it running:

```
ps aux  | grep dotnet
21569 1001      0:00 dotnet ConsoleApp32.dll
```

So running as uid 1001.
I then check host for this user:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
man
postmaster
cron
ftp
sshd
at
squid
xfs
games
postgres
cyrus
vpopmail
ntp
smmsp
guest
nobody
dockremap
```

No sign of appuser. My understanding(which may be wrong) is we are using a shared Kernel and user should be in list.
I also looked up uid

```
getent passwd 1001
```

Which returned no result.
Can someone explain this, as I dont understand how a process is running on host as a uid of 1001 and there is no associated user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user ID *is* shared with the host: it’s 1001.  The *name* of that user comes from looking it up in the `/etc/passwd` file.  Since the host and container have different filesystem spaces, they have different passwd files; the kernel doesn’t know anything about a user’s name.

The corresponding FAQ: it doesn’t matter if you have users named `pat` on both the host and in the container; if their numeric user IDs don’t match up, and you’re on Linux, and you’re trying to share content with `docker run -v`, one user won’t be able to access the other’s files.